# How to get TimeSpan from DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

Scenario:

Third party web service returns `datetime` in two separate fields i.e. date and time. I need a way to concatenate into single field.

```
e.g.

 startDate='24-06-2012'
 startTime='1-01-1970 1:00:00 AM'

Expected result:
 fullStartDateTime='24-06-2012 1:00:00 AM'
```

I tried to get the TimeSpan part from startTime and got no where. Could someone let me know if there's a smart way to achieve above.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) is the property of *DateTime* that you're looking for:

```
TimeSpan timeOfDay = startTime.TimeOfDay;
DateTime fullStartDateTime = startDate.Add(timeOfDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

`timespan fr = new timespan();
fr.parse(string date)`