# Timespan Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan, datarow

I am trying to display the time in a gridview column but when loading the information I get this error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

```
protected override void FillObject(DataRow dr)
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
            if (dr["Company_ID"] != DBNull.Value)
                CompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Company_ID"]);
           if (dr["LoginTime"] != DBNull.Value)
               LoginTime = (TimeSpan)(dr["LoginTime"]); //error
}
```

Get/Set code:

```
public TimeSpan LoginTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the `LoginTime` data type in SQL?

Comment: @S.Akbari it is `DATETIME`

Comment: There's your problem. `DATETIME` corresponds to `DateTime`, not `TimeSpan`. Change your property type and see what you can figure out then.

Comment: @TimS. yes you are right. Changed the data type to `Time` and it works now. Thanks

Comment: I thought `datetime` would be the right choice. If this is supposed to track a point in time (date, hour, minute, second) then it should be `datetime`. If it's just supposed to track a time of day, e.g. "8 am regardless of which day", then `time` is right.

Comment: @TimS. it is only to track the time

Answer (score 0):

As @TimS. pointed out, you need to use a `DateTime` variable in your code to consume a Sql Server `DATETIME`.  From that, you can convert it into a `TimeSpan` if necessary.

`public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }`

`LoginTime = (DateTime)(dr["LoginTime"]);`

To convert between the two, see [How to get TimeSpan from DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184718/how-to-get-timespan-from-datetime)